# Limit table entires by Primary Key

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

In a SQL Server table, I'm looking to set a constraint of sorts on the maximum number of entries that a primary key can have in that table. A potential use case for this type of scenario may be where, say, you'd like to restrict the maximum number of pictures that a user can store.

Presumably, you'd have a table called `Users_With_Pictures` or something similar and each user can only have 10 pictures. How could I restrict that user from only having 10 entries in the table? Is this best done on the presentation layer with no set controls on the database?

Comment: Any particular database?

Comment: I'm working with SQL Server.

Comment: You could e.g. add a `PictureNo` column to your `Users_With_Pictures` link table, which would be a counter per user, and add a `CHECK` constraint to that column to limit it to 10.

Comment: If I were to attempt an INSERT when a user has 10 pictures, how would the CHECK constraint react?

Comment: If you try to insert a row with a value `PictureNo=11` into that table with the `CHECK` constraint in place, you'll get an exception and the data is **not** inserted

Comment: Formulate a proper answer and I'll pass you the check mark. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of implementing any sort of SQL exception handling, I would think that enforcing at the presentation layer plus the constraint to ensure that my data integrity is maintained would be a good route. Is this the case @marc_s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could e.g. add a `PictureNo` column to your `Users_With_Pictures` link table, which would be a counter per user, and add a `CHECK` constraint to that column to limit it to 10.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users_with_Pictures
(
   ... your other columns ...
   PictureNo INT NOT NULL 
      CONSTRAINT CK_PictureNo CHECK(PictureNo > 0 AND PictureNo <= 10)
)
```

So when you insert a new row into `Users_with_Pictures` and you increase the `PictureNo` by 1 for each picture, once you've reached 10 pictures, the next insert with `PictureNo = 11` will fail with a constraint violation exception.

But of course - if you can handle this in your front end, even better! You can still leave the `CHECK` constraint in place - just to be sure that it will be enforced, even if someone manages to somehow get around your checks in the frontend (e.g. by disabling Javascript in the browser for a web app).

Comment: Great answer. I'm curious if you could just comment on your last statement a bit. So I should implement some sort of custom SQL exception handling. If somebody disables JS and manages to loop an INSERT, I don't want them to see an ASP.net SQL exception. So, custom exception handling + check constraint + front end checks?

Comment: @user3308043: that would be the best option, yes - many folks always leave out the database-level constraints, claiming all user input is validated at the front end and in their application. But what if someone disables all client-side (Javascript) checks, and manages to somehow fire off an `INSERT` statement ? Better be safe than sorry! "Defense in depth" is the keyword - but put your validation and checks in only one single layer ....

Comment: I like it, thank you.